# Comparison of 1d and 3d accelerometers

Tags: accelerometer, comparison

I have to use an accelerometer in my project. The project demands high accuracy in measuring acceleration magnitude and phase in all the three axes. I am searching for a detailed comparison of using three 1d accelerometers or using a single 3d accelerometer for this project. The comparison should compare the two choices in the following aspects:
1_ Accuracy of measurement
2_ Ease of installation
3_ Ease of writing code to extract information from the raw data
4_ Cost

Comment: So, what's your EE question and take note that recommendations for products (including reports) are usually off-topic: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The question was about a comparison of two approaches, not a request for a product recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

This is an absolute no-brainer, even if just because if you use three 1D accelerometers, you will *never* be able to align them to the precision to which a 3D unit is aligned off the shelf.

At best, accuracy of measurement will be a toss-up.  If you use analog accelerometers, writing code will also be a toss-up, but if you use  digital unit/s with some sort of serial bus, digital wins coding ease hands down.  For all the other criteria, digital comes out on top as well.

If I'm missing any factors, they probably have to do with the specifics of your project, which you haven't shared